# (Unity) Why is my list of a class not getting saved in JSON

Tags: arrays, json, list, unity-game-engine

I want to save a list of dialogue items. I made a script called dialogue item which is just one message, I made an array of that so it can be a conversation, and I made a list of that conversation so that I can have multiple conversations.

```
[SerializeField] public List<DialogueList> dialogue = new List<DialogueList();
```

So I made this variable of a class named DialogueList, that contains the dialogueitems.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class DialogueList
{
    [SerializeField] public string convoName;
    [SerializeField] public int dialogueID;
    [SerializeField] public DialogueItem[] dialogues;
}
```

I want to save these conversations so that I can load them in specific languages in later stages. But for some reason my JSON file is empty when I try to save my variable named dialogue.

```
    string jsonData = JsonUtility.ToJson(dialogue, true);
    string _fullPath = "/caroline-dialogue" + ".json";
    File.WriteAllText(Application.persistentDataPath + _fullPath, jsonData);
```

I tried using a different method, that actually works, but it can get really messy.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < dialogue.Count; i++)
    {
        string jsonData = JsonUtility.ToJson(dialogue[i], true);
        string _fullPath = "/caroline-dialogue-" + i + ".json";
        File.WriteAllText(Application.persistentDataPath + _fullPath, jsonData);

    }
```

My question is: What am I doing wrong? Am I forgetting something? My guess it that something is wrong with the variable named dialogue, since saving all the dialogueitems with a for loop works.

I hope I explained my problem well enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serialization/deserialization of the arrays or lists is not supported using the `JsonUtility`. You would need to wrap the list in a serializable class:

```
[Serializable]
private class DialogueListWrapper
{
    public List<DialogueList> objects;
}
```

Comment: Also, make sure that `DialogueItem` is serializable too.

Comment: Good point, though as I understand arrays do work if they are a field, and are not passed to the `JsonUtility` by themselves.

Comment: Haven't messed with it myself, but I believe you are correct. My comment was more of a "if the type of the array is itself not serialized, it still won't work!" Builtin types would be fine, of course, but custom types would still need `[SerializedField]`s and so forth.

Comment: Oh, sorry, misunderstood. Yeah, that's also required. You can post another answer to specify this, but it seems like OP have resolved the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I had already serialized nearly everything, but the solution Krypt1 provided worked.